# Reformatting a JSON Date

Tags: json, powershell, date-formatting

I am using PowerShell and `Invoke-WebRequest` to return JSON date and time information from http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Europe/Dublin. One if the fields returned is named `datetime` and contains the value `2019-06-07T13:21:25.567490+01:00`. I want to format this string into a more readable friendly format, but I can't find a way. My code is:

```
$request = 'http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Europe/Dublin'
$data = Invoke-WebRequest $request | ConvertFrom-Json
$x = $data.datetime
$x
$x.GetType().Name
$y = [datetime]::Parse($x)
$y
$y.GetType().Name
```

And the values returned are:

```
2019-06-07T13:38:20.494332+01:00
String

Friday, June 7, 2019 8:38:20 AM
DateTime
```

The first date time is from Dublin and is correct, but the second is my local date and time.

Comment: Try `([DateTimeOffset] $data.datetime).ToString()`. You can also supply a [standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings) or [custom](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) format string to `ToString`.

Comment: Why didn't you make this answer that I could accept instead of a comment. Your suggestion works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was submitted as a comment:

Try `([DateTimeOffset] $data.datetime).ToString()`. You can also supply a standard or custom format string to ToString. – Jeroen Mostert Jun 7 at 13:06